# How to check if the given lines are coplanar?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have two lines:
$$\frac{x-1}{3}=\frac{y+2}{-2}=\frac{z}{1} = L_1$$
$$ \frac{x+1}{4} = \frac{y-3}{1}=\frac{z}{\alpha} =L_2$$

How can I find the value of $\alpha$ for which these two lines lie on the same plane?

Just notice that this is not a homework question. I took it from an exam held a few years ago, and got no idea about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examine both lines in parametric form. If their vectors are parallel then they are certainly coplanar. If their vectors are not parallel, two lines are coplanar if and only iff they intersect; otherwise, they are skew.

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{align*}(L_1)&\;\;z=\frac{x-1}3\;,\;\;\;\;y=\frac{-2x+2}3-2=\frac{-2x-4}3\\
(L_2)&\;\;z=\frac{\alpha x+\alpha}4\;,\;\;y=\frac{x+13}4\end{align*}$$

Suppose there exists a plane $\,ax+by+cz+d=0\;$ which contains both lines, then we have

$$ax+b\left(\frac{-2x-4}3\right)+c\left(\frac{x-1}3\right)=ax+b\left(\frac{x+13}4\right)+c\left(\frac{\alpha x+\alpha}4\right)\iff$$

$$\left(\frac{11}{12}b+\frac{3\alpha-4}{12}c\right)x+\left(\frac{55}{12}b+\frac{3\alpha+4}{12}c\right)=0$$

and from here we get

$$\begin{align*}11b&=(-3\alpha+4)c\\
55b&=(-3\alpha-4)c\end{align*}$$

Divide second eq. by first one above and get your value of $\,\alpha=2\,$ ...

Comment: You're welcome, @Calculus2222 . Note though that you can *upvote* as many questions as you like (usually, the ones that helped you in some way), though you can **choose** only one: that that you think helped you the most.

Comment: This one is more illustrating. (+1)