# Proving that two lines are not from the same plane?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Well,

I'm looking for a clean but effective way to prove that two lines in the space are or are not from the same plane, knowing that these two lines are given by their parametric representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you a useful link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity

Related: [How to check if the lines are coplanar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434824/how-to-check-if-the-lines-are-coplanar)

So just prove what you desire to by showing the inequality in the formulae; if you still have doubts, leave a comment; I'll give a bigger hint or a solution.

Edit: See this [Coplanarity of two lines in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046828/coplanarity-of-two-lines-in-3d)

Comment: Well, now i can understand that both parallelism and intersection imply the coplanarity and only one of them is enough to prove it, i know how to check parallelism but not sure about the intersection so if you could please give us a hint about how to do that considering the definition (parametric representation).

Comment: Are you comfortable with matrices? If so, check this for the conditions which are to be satisfied by two lines: http://mathumatiks.com/subpage-367-Conditions-for-the-two-lines-to-intersect-or-Coplanar.htm

Comment: ah, that's unfortunate :(, i'm not.

Comment: It's alright. Just give me a minute.

Comment: I've added a link. Check that.

Comment: Thanks, i can understand you quite well, your links were pretty useful (I don't supposed to be thanking you here though, but it worths) :).

Comment: Your welcome sir! If the answer was useful, then please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer by ticking.

Comment: Your information are more important than up-voting it, however i forget to do that.

Comment: It's okay! Thank you for the compliment.

Answer (score 3):

If the lines are defined by the parametric representations (I use a synthetic notation, in terms of points and vectors):
$$ M =A +t \mkern 1.5mu\vec u, \qquad  M =B +t \mkern 1.5mu\vec v$$
they're coplanar iff and only if the vectors $\vec u, \vec v, \overrightarrow{AB}$ are linearly dependent, in other words if
$$\det(\vec u, \vec v, \overrightarrow{AB})=0.$$

Comment: det here is the Determinant right?

Comment: OP stated he isn't comfortable with matrices.

Comment: Alright, i can understand you guys.

Comment: Then he/she has to solve linear equations. Gauß's row reduction and the like.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, solving the system of linear equations would do that.

Comment: @Antaraz: if you only want to show the lines aare coplanar, you only have to show the system of equations has solutions, without having to solve them. That amounts to computing the determinant. A harder problem would be to find an equation for the plane that contains the lines.

Comment: Exactly, we just need to check whether the system has solutions, but it's good to check what kind of solutions it has i.e: unlimited number of solutions imply that they are the same line though.

Comment: If you are given a *family* of lines that depend on a parameter such a situation may happen.